# How to convert a QtSoapArray to QStringList in Blackberry

Tags: soap, blackberry, tstringlist

I am new to BlackBerry Devevelopment. How can i convert a **QtSoapArray** to **QStringList**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this like,

Here **m_ListEmails** is QtSoapArray and **m_Emails1** is QStringList

```
        for (int var = 0; var < m_Emails1.count(); ++var) {
            m_ListEmails.append(m_Emails1[var].toString());
            qDebug() << "Email: "+ m_Emails1[var].toString();
        }
```